# Do you know any fax card T0 BRI supported by VMWare VSphere 4.1?

Tags: fax, vmware-vsphere

Is there someone who know if we can use a Fax T0 BRI card on VMWare VSphere 4.1?

The manufacturer and price doesn't matter for informations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think either hypervisor (ESX/ESXi) supports BRI or BRI fax cards. This is confirmed by the VM Community [here](http://communities.vmware.com/message/396541#396541) and on the Vmware (I/O) [compatibility guide](http://www.vmware.com/resources/compatibility/search.php?action=base&deviceCategory=io). I would try a serial attached solution if an IP based fax option is less desirable.

Comment: Ok many thanks for your support, I've choose to put the Fax card and software into my VCenter Server wich is over sized for just serve VCenter.